# How do I set the path in my rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I set the path?

I get the following error when I run my rails application:

```
No route matches {:action=>"search", :controller=>"inbox"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

I think this has to do with my routes.rb file. 
I am working on a search bar and every time I search, it loops back to the main page since I do not have a path set.

This is my index.erb.html file.

```
    <%= form_tag inbox_search_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <p>
      <%= search_field_tag :Search, params[:search] %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

And this is my routes.rb file.

```
   Rails.application.routes.draw do

   resources :webinars
   resources :topic_proposals
   resources :webinar_questions

   get 'webinars/show/' => 'webinars#show', :as => 'webinars_show'
   get 'webinars/edit/:id' => 'webinars#edit', :as => 'webinars_edit'
   get 'webinars/delete_webinar/:id' => 'webinars#delete_webinar', :as =>   'webinars_delete_webinar'

   resources :categories_skills

   resources :categories


   get 'home/download_pdf'

   get 'static/:view' => 'static#show', :as => 'static'

   get 'lists/:id/members' => 'lists#members', :as => 'list_members'
   post 'lists/:id/update_mailchimp_list' => 'lists#update_mailchimp', :as => 'update_mailchimp_list'
   # put 'lists/:id/' => 'lists#update', :as => 'list_update'
   # get  'lists' => 'lists#index', :as => 'lists'
   resources :lists

   resources :emails
   post 'emails/upload' => 'emails#upload', :as => 'upload_emails'

   resources :campaigns
   resources :affiliates
   resources :answers
   resources :questions
   resources :messages
   resources :schools
   resources :payments
   resources :assessments do
   resources :questions do
   resources :responses
   end
   end
   get 'tryout' => "tryout#index"

   get 'take/assessments' => 'take_assessment#show', :as => 'take_assessments'
   get 'take/assessments/start' => 'take_assessment#start', :as => 'start_assessments'
   get 'take/assessments/summary' => 'take_assessment#summary', :as => 'summary_assessment'
   get 'take/assessments/select_school_year' => 'take_assessment#select_school_year', :as => 'select_school_year'

   get 'quiz-results' => 'quiz_results#summary', :as => 'quiz-results'

   match 'connect/mentors' => 'connect_mentors#index', :as => 'connect_mentors', via: [:get, :post]

   get 'connect/mentors/:id' => 'connect_mentors#show', :as => 'show_mentor'
   get 'connect/students/:id' => 'connect_students#show', :as => 'show_student'

   devise_scope :user do
   get 'partners/:invitation_code' => 'partners#landing', as:  'partners_landing'
   get 'partners/:code/new' => 'partners#new', as: 'partners_new'
   post 'partners' => 'partners#create', as: 'partners_registration'
   end

   devise_scope :user do
   get 'members/new' => 'members#new', as: 'members_new'
   get 'members/new/:variation' => 'members#new', as: 'members_new_variation'
   post 'members' => 'members#create', as: 'members_registration'
   end

   resource :user, only: [:edit] do
   collection do
   patch 'update_password'
   patch 'update_notification_email'
   patch 'update_school_year_id', :controller=>"take_assessment"
   end
   end

   get 'learn' => "lesson_plans#index"
   get 'lesson-plans/:id' => 'lesson_plans#show', as: 'lesson_plan'
   get 'content/:id' => 'content#show', as: :content
   get 'content/:id/review' => 'content#review', as: 'content_review'

   get 'mentors/:id/conversation' => 'conversations#index', as: 'mentor_conversation'
   get 'mentors/:id/conversations/new' => 'conversations#new', as: 'new_mentor_conversation'

   get 'profile' => 'profile#show', as: 'user_profile'

   get 'redeem' => 'redeem_invitations#validate_redeem_code', as: 'redeem_code'

   resources :request_invitations
   resources :payment_types
   resources :articles
   resources :skills
   resources :portals
   resources :school_sessions
   resources :school_years
   resources :conversations do
   resource :messages, only: [:new, :create]
   end
   resources :grade_levels
   resources :messages, only: [:index, :show]
   resources :lookup do
   get :lookup_mentor_name, :on => :collection
   get :lookup_student_name, :on => :collection
   end

   get 'inbox' => 'inbox#index', :as => 'inbox_index'
   get 'inbox/show/:id' => 'inbox#show', :as => 'inbox_show'
   get 'inbox/compose' => 'inbox#compose', :as => 'inbox_compose'
   get 'inbox/compose/:id' => 'inbox#compose', :as => 'inbox_compose_to'
   get 'inbox/edit/:id' => 'inbox#edit', :as => 'inbox_edit'
   get 'inbox/move' => 'inbox#move', :as => 'inbox_move'
   get 'inbox/reply' => 'inbox#reply', :as => 'inbox_reply'
   post 'inbox/create' => 'inbox#create'
   post 'inbox/bulk' => 'inbox#bulk'


   post 'memberships/agree' => 'memberships#agree'
   get 'memberships/new' => 'memberships#new', :as => 'memberships_new'
   get 'memberships/terms' => 'memberships#terms', :as => 'memberships_terms'
   get 'memberships/success/:id' => 'memberships#success', :as => 'memberships_success'
   get 'memberships/failure' => 'memberships#failure', :as => 'memberships_failure'
   get 'memberships/paypal_payment' => 'memberships#paypal_payment', :as => 'paypal_payment'
   get 'memberships/paypal_payment_step_2' => 'memberships#paypal_payment_step_2', :as => 'paypal_payment_step_2'
   resources :memberships
   post 'memberships/hook' => 'memberships#hook'

   get 'admin/dashboard/export_cert' => 'admin_dashboard#export_certs', :as => 'admin_dashboard_export_cert'
   get 'admin/dashboard/registrations' => 'admin_dashboard#registrations', :as => 'admin_dashboard_registrations'
   get 'admin/dashboard/payments' => 'admin_dashboard#payments', :as => 'admin_dashboard_payments'
   get 'admin/dashboard/schoolreports' => 'admin_dashboard#schoolreports', :as => 'admin_dashboard_schoolreports'
   get 'admin/dashboard/memberreports' => 'admin_dashboard#memberreports', :as => 'admin_dashboard_memberreports'
   get 'admin/dashboard/messagingreports' => 'admin_dashboard#messagingreports', :as => 'admin_dashboard_messagingreports'
   get 'admin/dashboard/messaging_mentor_reports' =>     'admin_dashboard#messaging_mentor_reports', :as =>   'admin_dashboard_messaging_mentor_reports'
   get 'admin/dashboard/load_points' => 'admin_dashboard#load_points', :as => 'admin_dashboard_load_points'
   get 'admin/dashboard/reset_points' => 'admin_dashboard#reset_points', :as => 'admin_dashboard_reset_points'
   get 'admin/dashboard/activate_membership' => 'admin_dashboard#activate_membership', :as => 'admin_dashboard_activate_membership'
   get 'admin/dashboard/delete_account' => 'admin_dashboard#delete_account', :as => 'admin_dashboard_delete_account'
   get 'admin/dashboard/reset_password/:id' => 'admin_dashboard#reset_password', :as => 'admin_dashboard_reset_password'
   get 'admin/members/edit/:id' => 'admin_dashboard#edit', :as => 'edituser'
   get 'admin/dashboard/unpaid_members' => 'admin_dashboard#unpaid_members', :as => 'unpaid_members'
   patch 'admin/members/edit/:id' => 'admin_dashboard#update' # new code

   get 'admin/dashboard/expired_messages' => 'admin_dashboard#expired_messages', :as => 'admin_dashboard_expired_messages'
   get 'admin/dashboard/' => 'admin_dashboard#search', :as => 'admin_dashboard'
   get 'admin/demo_list/' => 'admin_dashboard#demo_list', :as => 'demo_list'
   get 'admin/cleandata/:id' => 'admin_dashboard#data_cleanup', :as => 'data_cleanup'
   post 'admin/dashboard/upload' => 'admin_dashboard#upload', :as => 'upload_admin_dashboard'

    get 'admin/mentors' => 'mentors#index', :as => 'admin_mentors'
   post 'admin/mentors' => 'mentors#create'
   get 'admin/mentors/new' => 'mentors#new', :as => 'admin_new_mentor'
    get 'admin/mentors/:id' => 'mentors#show', :as => 'admin_mentor'

   get 'admin/impersonate'=> 'admin_dashboard#impersonate', :as => 'admin_impersonate'
   get 'admin/stop_impersonating'=> 'admin_dashboard#stop_impersonating', :as => 'admin_stop_impersonating'
   get 'messages/reply/:id' => 'messages#reply', as: 'reply_to'
    get 'credits/new', as: 'new_credits'

    get 'dashboard' => 'dashboard#index', as: 'user_root'
    get 'seen_message' => 'dashboard#seen_message', as: 'seen_message'

    devise_for :users, :controllers   => {registrations: 'registrations',  passwords: 'passwords'}

    # The static site pages
    get 'about' => "pages#about", :as => 'about'
    get 'joinus' => "pages#membership", :as => 'joinus'
    get 'faq' => "pages#faq", :as => "faq"
    get 'certification' => "pages#certification", :as => "certification"
    get 'chapters' => "pages#chapters", :as => "chapters"

    get 'internships' => 'pages#internships', :as => 'internships'
    get 'privacy-policy' => 'pages#privacy_policy', :as => 'privacy_policy'
    get 'contact-us' => 'pages#contact_us', :as => 'contact_us'
    post 'send_message' => "pages#send_message", :as => 'send_contact_us'
    get 'terms-of-use' => 'pages#terms', :as => 'terms'

    #temporary
    get 'pages/accountinfo' => 'pages#accountinfo', :as => "pages_accountinfo"
    get 'pages/registration' => 'pages#registration', :as => "pages_registration"
    get 'pages/payment' => 'pages#payment', :as => "pages_payment"

    # leadership pages
    get 'leadership' => 'leadership#index'
    get 'leadership/recruitment' => 'leadership#recruitment', :as => "leadership_recruitment"
    get 'leadership/advisory' => 'leadership#advisory', :as => "leadership_advisory"
    get 'leadership/fredsiegel' => 'leadership#fredsiegel', :as => :fredsiegel
    get 'leadership/matttrainum' => 'leadership#matttrainum', :as => :matttrainum
    get 'leadership/lenormanstrong' => 'leadership#lenormanstrong', :as => :lenormanstrong
    get 'leadership/arlenecash' => 'leadership#arlenecash', :as => :arlenecash
    get 'leadership/ernestolopez' => 'leadership#ernestolopez', :as => :ernestolopez
    get 'leadership/rodneyjohnson' => 'leadership#rodneyjohnson', :as => :rodneyjohnson
    get 'leadership/carolaweil' => 'leadership#carolaweil', :as => :carolaweil
    get 'leadership/dianenafranowicz' => 'leadership#dianenafranowicz', :as => :dianenafranowicz
    get 'leadership/alexakim' => 'leadership#alexakim', :as => :alexakim
    get 'leadership/robertkirkwood' => 'leadership#robertkirkwood', :as => :robertkirkwood
    get 'leadership/jodyhubbard' => 'leadership#jodyhubbard', :as => :jodyhubbard
    get 'leadership/bobbydishell' => 'leadership#bobbydishell', :as => :bobbydishell
    get 'leadership/paulhimmelfarb' => 'leadership#paulhimmelfarb', :as => :paulhimmelfarb
    get 'leadership/nedjohnson' => 'leadership#nedjohnson', :as => :nedjohnson
    get 'leadership/patsidhu' => 'leadership#patsidhu', :as => :patsidhu
    get 'leadership/product' => 'pages#product', :as => :product

    # internship pages


    resources :internship_application
    get 'internship' => 'internship_application#index', :as => 'internship'


    # Payments Search

    get 'internship' => 'payments#search', :as => :paymentssearch
    # feature pages
    get 'feature/mentor' => 'feature#mentor', :as => "feature_mentor"
    get 'feature/advisor' => 'feature#advisor', :as => "feature_advisor"

     get 'memberships/accountinfo' => 'memberships#accountinfo', :as => "membership_accountinfo"
     resources :contacts, only:[:new, :create]

     root 'home#index'

     # We need this line to catch any routing error
     match '*path(.:format)', :to => 'application#not_found', via: :all
     end
```

This is my relevant part of route.rb file.

```
get 'inbox' => 'inbox#index', :as => 'inbox_index'
get 'inbox/show/:id' => 'inbox#show', :as => 'inbox_show'
get 'inbox/compose' => 'inbox#compose', :as => 'inbox_compose'
get 'inbox/compose/:id' => 'inbox#compose', :as => 'inbox_compose_to'
get 'inbox/edit/:id' => 'inbox#edit', :as => 'inbox_edit'
get 'inbox/move' => 'inbox#move', :as => 'inbox_move'
get 'inbox/reply' => 'inbox#reply', :as => 'inbox_reply'
post 'inbox/create' => 'inbox#create'
post 'inbox/bulk' => 'inbox#bulk'
get 'inbox/search' => 'inbox#seaarch', :as => 'inbox_search'
```

Comment: Maybe just include the relevant portion(s) of the routes file.

Comment: Where is `inbox_search_path` in routes file?

Comment: Ok. I figured out the routes. But everytime I click search it says The action 'search' cannot be found for InboxController.

Comment: I can't see any such route defined in route file. Please post complete route file. But what i can see from errors that inbox_search_path is a member route and it requires id which you have to pass it as inbox_search_path(:id => some_id).
But for searching we use collection route which works on collection and doesn't require id.

Comment: @ShailiParikh you should edit your post to only show the relevant portion of routes file, because by coping and pasting all that code here exposes your application to the world.

Comment: Sure. Give me a minute.

Comment: @Donato can you see it now?

Answer (score 2):

Add this route to your routes.rb

```
get 'inbox/search' => 'inbox#search', :as => inbox_search
```

Comment: is it supposed to be inbox_search or 'inbox_search'?

Answer (score 2):

it looks like your route has a spelling error which could cause it to fail.

```
get 'inbox/search' => 'inbox#seaarch', :as => 'inbox_search'
                                ^
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I have the right spelling yet it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

So changing your `form_tag` to this:

```
<%= form_tag '/inbox/search', :method => 'get' do %>
    <p>
      <%= search_field_tag :Search, params[:search] %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

should fix your `path helper` problem. as to why you're getting that error it looks like `inbox_search_path` is expecting you to pass in an `id` so either you changed your route file, you need to bounce your server, or you need to paste the rest of your html file.